# The order of variable assignment

Tags: c++

The following is adapted from a code:

```
void func()
{
  static MyClass a = init_func();

  a_global_var = null;
}
```

Does C++ compiler guarantees that the first assignment is before the 2nd?

Comment: You should ask a new question rather than editing your current one to a different one. Now my answer makes no sense.

Comment: I'm reverting the change, that should be a new question. Moreover, your modified code won't compile anymore because you can't have arbitrary assignments happening outside functions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. But I shudder to think why you need to rely on this.

The first time the function is called, `a` is initialized with whatever is returned from `init_func` before `a_global_var` is later set to "`null`"

Note that as `a` is static, this only happens the first time the function is called. All subsequent times, `a_global_var` is set to `null` without any change to `a` by this function.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I just updated my question, actually those 2 statements are outside any function.

Comment: Using a static variable in a function is a fairly normal pattern

Comment: @MattMcNabb Is using a static variable in a function which requires a global variable to be manually set to null afterwards a normal pattern?

Comment: I'm just talking about the static variable. it could be paired with any other construct.

Answer (score 1):

The first line is not an "assignment". It is an *initialization*. Since it is an initialization of a *static* object declared in block scope, it will be performed only once, when the control passes over it for the very first time, i.e. when you call your function for the first time.

The second line is indeed an assignment. It will be executed every time the control passes over it, i.e. every time you call your function.

This means that your question only makes sense for the first time this function is called. In that case the initialization is guaranteed to precede the assignment. In all subsequent calls the question will not apply at all, since the initialization will not be performed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Does C++ compiler guarantees that the first assignment is before the 2nd?"*

Yes, it's guaranteed.

Anyway you should consider to handle this in a singleton (if you really need to have it globally accessible):

```
class MyClass {
public:
    static MyClass& instance() { // <<< replaces func()
        static MyClass a;
        return a;
    }

    void* global_var() { return a_global_var; }
private:
    MyClass() : a_global_var(nullptr) { // <<< replaces init_func()
    }
    void* a_global_var;

};
```